# IP address management for embedded systems under development

Tags: .net, tcp, embedded

We are adding a TCPIP stack to our embedded systems. Each system under development will communicate to a custom .net app running on the software engineer's computer. It is assumed that IT will dictate use of static IP addresses for each embedded system and a subnet for the group of them. But I wonder if there is a simple protocol that each embedded system can publish upon bootup that would allow us to use IT-preferred DHCP addresses on the embedded system but still allow the .net app to find a dynamically assigned IP address on the software engineer's embedded system under development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DHCP protocol includes a "Host Name Option" that allows clients to inform the server of their names. Ask your IT department if they will support this option so that the embedded devices can be looked up by name. IF so, instead of fixing the IP address, just fix the name.

Comment: Turns out your idea is great but that requires IT to connect DHCP to DNS so one can query DNS for that name. This fortune 500 client is unlikely to make that kind of change for our little embedded system. Even in our own self-managed IT network, we'd have to figure out how to connect DHCP to DNS on our windows SBS server which none of us knows how to do just to test the idea.

Comment: @levocs Since you are bound by client requirements, you might want to ask them how they handle similar devices--for example, printers. That might lead you to a workable solution.

Comment: Turns out your idea is the right solution. Googling SBS 2011 DNS DHCP yielded answers for how we need to configure our server to allow DHCP to add the supplied hostname to DNS and that solves our need. The client is willing to make that change internally for their network. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use the Microchip TCP/IP Stack in embedded devices.  It has a library for NetBIOS.  This lets a PC ping a name and the embedded device responds.  The trick to using NetBIOS is now each embedded device has the same name and needs to be configured differently before the next device comes online.  One idea was to set the NetBIOS name to the serial number of the unit.  Our serial numbers were stored in the configuration of the units.

Comment: Good thinking thank you. We're using lwip. It appears netbios for that gnu stack is not supported (I can't find it). I see multiple posted netbios implementations but hesitate to bring in unsupported functionality. It is already painful enough to get basic lwip functionality to work. I can just see adding something unsupported and running into more troubles.